# curve fitting not optimistic using scipy curve_fit

Tags: python, r, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a curve using self defined function. I have the data points in the log-log plot, shown as below:
[image]

x axis is `logr`, y axis is `logf`. For the data point with negative value, I use the upper error bar as the data pint, for the data point with undefined lower error bar, I set to a certain value.

From the plot, we can see the data point is pretty much a **straight line + a tail (tail starts approximately from -0.6 to the end)**.  So I assume the original data has the following behavior and the data is also below:

```
f = a * r^b + c
r = [ 0.00528039  0.00721161  0.00873037  0.01108928  0.01413011  0.01790143 0.02263833  0.02886089  0.03663713  0.04659512  0.05921978  0.07540126 0.09593949  0.12190075  0.15501736  0.19713563  0.25041524  0.31850255 0.40514023  0.51507869  0.65489938  0.83278859  1.05865016  1.34624082]   
f = [ 0.07905728  0.04011504  0.03490303  0.03138561  0.01401272  0.0053508 0.00546048  0.00296805  0.00041698  0.00078639  0.00235994  0.00221327 0.00115695  0.0008026   0.00054334  0.00052034  0.00089253  0.000486 0.0008194   0.00073325  0.00071894  0.00066874  0.00066106  0.00064371]
```

But directly fitting to the above function is horrible, because the point drops so quickly. So I modify the fitting function like below:

```
def fit_func(x,a,b,c):
xx = a * x**b
xxx = 10**xx + 10**c
return np.log10(xxx)

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(fit_func, r, f)
f_fit = fit_func(r,popt[0],popt[1],popt[2])
```

Although I put the error bars in the plot, but it is not important in the curve fitting. I  use scipy.optimize to do the fit, the black line below is the fit.  But the fitting curves too quick. Any one has better idea to do the fit? Or any one can offer me some idea how to calculate the uncertainties of the fitting parameters `a, b, c`, because I am trying to write the fitting module myself.

Comment: When you want to fit a non-linear function, you should first look at the process that generated this data and decide on a model based on the science behind it. E.g., the model for radioactive decay can be derived easily from a simple differential equation. Anyway, this is off-topic here and I've voted to close.

Comment: And of course, you should take care that you correctly represent the residual distribution and variance heterogeneity in your model.

Answer (score 2):

Your logarithmic model underweight last points, so only firsts points are taken in account.

other attempt :

```
def model(r,r0,f0,k): return (r0/r)**k +f0 
p0=(1e-1,1e-3,2)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(model, r, f,p0)
plot(r,f,'ro',r,model(r,*popt),'b')
```

For

[image]

the black curve is a model without the green point, which clearly is a "bad" point for the model.

But due to your noisy data, and because you knows errors, use the `sigma` parameter of `curve_fit`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried your model, but it looks like the parameter f0 is setting too high, it is around 1.0 instead of 1.0e-3. Then I can not interpret it.